# Can't understand a behaviour of the floor function

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, casting, floor

I'm working in Python 2.7.13

I have this simple code :

```
import math

a = [1,3,9,10,11,56,99,100,101,106,555,998,999,1000,1001,1102,9999,10000,10001,10002]

for i in a:
    print "%d : log : %f / floor : %f / int : %d" %(i, math.log(i,10), math.floor(math.log(i,10)), int(math.log(i,10)))
```

I want to try the log function on different numbers, and see what happen when I use the floor function on the result or cast it into an integer

And the output is :

```
1 : log : 0.000000 / floor : 0.000000 / int : 0
3 : log : 0.477121 / floor : 0.000000 / int : 0
9 : log : 0.954243 / floor : 0.000000 / int : 0
10 : log : 1.000000 / floor : 1.000000 / int : 1
11 : log : 1.041393 / floor : 1.000000 / int : 1
56 : log : 1.748188 / floor : 1.000000 / int : 1
99 : log : 1.995635 / floor : 1.000000 / int : 1
100 : log : 2.000000 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
101 : log : 2.004321 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
106 : log : 2.025306 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
555 : log : 2.744293 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
998 : log : 2.999131 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
999 : log : 2.999565 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
1000 : log : 3.000000 / floor : 2.000000 / int : 2
1001 : log : 3.000434 / floor : 3.000000 / int : 3
1102 : log : 3.042182 / floor : 3.000000 / int : 3
9999 : log : 3.999957 / floor : 3.000000 / int : 3
10000 : log : 4.000000 / floor : 4.000000 / int : 4
10001 : log : 4.000043 / floor : 4.000000 / int : 4
10002 : log : 4.000087 / floor : 4.000000 / int : 4
```

Everything works as expected except for the number 1000 : you can see that the log is 3.000000 but when I use the floor function it changes to 2.00000 and the integer is 2, when I wanted it to be 3

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you equality-compared the result to `3.0`, the expected result? It seems that the logarithmic function doesn't work 100% precise, which you shouldn't expect for float math anyway.

Comment: math.log(10, 1000) gives 2.999999999999996 , hence floor is 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the log function is not exact:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 11 2017, 16:08:01) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log(1000,10)
2.9999999999999996
```

This rounds to 3.0000 when you print it. `math.log10` is better:

```
>>> math.log10(1000)
3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got a float precision issue: check the value of `math.log(1000,10)`:

```
>>> math.log(1000,10)
2.9999999999999996
```

which means that `math.floor(math.log(1000,10))` will indeed result in `2`